Replacing multiple characters in single column in result set
So I am trying to create a fixed length flat file from the result set of this query, however there are three name fields where I have to strip out hyphens, apostrophes, spaces, periods, suffixes (Jr) or prefixes (Dr). The characters that are stripped out have to be deleted completely, not replaced by blank but each column width has to remain the same. So for example, last name is maxed at 13 characters in length:
Last name: McDonald-O'Leary
Should return as: McDonaldOLear
This is what I have so far, the only thing I am able to replace is a single character so far, a hyphen...
SELECT
    REPLACE(idNum, '-', '') +
    'ABC' +
    '123' +
    REPLACE(LEFT(lastname + REPLICATE(' ', 13), 13), '-', '') +
    REPLACE(LEFT(firstName + REPLICATE(' ', 10), 10), '-', '') +
    REPLACE(LEFT(middleName + REPLICATE(' ', 7), 7), '-', '') +
    REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), dateField, 101),'/','') +
    '                                    ' +
    REPLACE(LEFT(CLNum + REPLICATE(' ', 6), 6), '''', '') +
    REPLACE(LEFT(UID + REPLICATE(' ', 8), 8), '''', '') +
    '                    ' +
    'DEFG' +
    '000'
FROM TableName
WHERE CLNum = '1234'
AND ISNULL(dateField, '') <> ''

I've tried many variations on REPLACE, various positioning of extra character omissions inside and outside of each line and parens, but I cannot get the syntax to work.

Use the function TRANSLATE. This function can simply remove all unwanted characters at once, so this task becomes quite trivial. Upgrade your SQL Server DB version if the function is not available in your version.

Unfortunately upgrading is not an option for me, this is a server out of my control, I'm just consulting on trying to get data out of it for a Power BI project. I had seen various search results detailing TRANSLATE but naturally I'm unable to apply that syntax in this instance.

TRANSLATE is not available on the SQL Server 2016 instance I am running it against. The only way I have been able to improve upon my original query is by using NESTED REPLACE so far, like this:
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(left(lastname + replicate(' ', 13), 13), '-', ''), '''', ''), ' ', '') +
I'm just wondering if the added REPLICATE function that I need is adding to the issue too. I need to also add spaces to the column date if the data is less than 13 characters in length.

If you're using REPLACE, they need to be nested
REPLACE(REPLACE(OriginalString,' ',''),'-','')
For the correct length maybe you need to put the replacements into a CTE and correct the lengths using the CTE?

@strattonn It doesn't matter if they use a CTE or not, they can just write CAST(... AS VARCHAR(13)) to set a fixed length where ... is any string, for example that one in your comment.

Do the padding as the last thing you do on that column; otherwise each replace scans over the padding blanks (and you are removing the added blanks: left(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(lastname , '-', ''), '''', ''), ' ', '') + replicate(' ', 13), 13). You could also use CAST(.... AS CHAR(13)) to achive the same, but not sure if faster or slower

Thanks @tinazmu I had not thought of that, too much time looking at the same thing the brain starts to become a little numb. I am also resigned to using nested REPLACE statements it seems, but at this point what ever works, thanks everybody.

Do the padding as the last thing you do on that column; otherwise each replace scans over the padding blanks (and you are removing the added blanks:
left(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(lastname , '-', ''), '''', ''), ' ', '') + replicate(' ', 13), 13)

You could also use CAST(.... AS CHAR(13)) to achive the same padding, but not sure if faster or slower.
